# Background tile hatching animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, responsive

I have to template a design in which some of the content modules come with a hatching as a decoration element:

[image: content module with hatching]

Modules and therefore the hatchings alike are responsive, so module and hatching come in all sizes and aspect ratios imaginable. Hatchings can have different positions, too:

[image: content module and hatching, differerent size]

[image: content module and hatching, another size and position]

Obviously, these hatchings are realized with a simple SVG background tile:

[image: svg background tile]

**Here is the problem:**
The design department came up with an animation for the hatching, where the lines start at different lengths and grow, until every line arrives at its final length:

[image: animation idea]

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't figure out how to build this responsively. Of course I could use a lottieFile or even a video, but these would scale line width and spaces responsively - and that's out of the question.

The design department already sold the animation to the customer, so I really have to find a way ... any suggestions?

EDIT: provided some sample code:

MORE EDIT: You have to switch to "Full page" when running the code snippet to see the correct rendering of the elements ... weird ...

```css
  .grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75vw;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 75vh;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 100px;
  }

  .contentElement {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    z-index: 2;

    padding: 40px;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }

  .hatching {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
    z-index: 1;

    /* background-image: url(img/background/tile_hatching_l.svg); */
    /* background-repeat: repeat; */
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- grid -->
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="contentElement">
      This is the content element
    </div>
    <div class="hatching"></div>
  </div>
<!-- end grid -->
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand, I suppose the hatching, based on the images you included, is ment to be something like shadow of an element, that will be gradually rendered as the page loads?

Comment: Well you could think of it as a kind of shadow that consists of lines with a defined width and space between the lines - which can be achieved easily by using a background tile (like I do). The trouble is that this "shadow" is supposed to have an animation that effects some lines in a different way than others without rescaling line width or space between the lines.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that content element and hatching are separated divs within a common grid. The grid is affected by the size of the content element.

Comment: I would need some of your code to try to recreate the animation on my localhost

Comment: Ok, I will create a simplified code example - give me a moment, please :)

Comment: added sample code :)

Comment: Can be done with CSS only

Comment: @Floyd your sample code is not even close to the proposed images. At least getting that *"underlay"* element right is a good start? So, If I got the question right, someone proposed to animate every stripe line into place individually?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes it is :) The hatching is a div that lies underneath the content element and has a background tile that creates the lines - very simple. Only that I commented out the css lines for the background tile and added a background color instead.

Comment: @vsync that's a relief to hear. Will you tell me how? :)

Comment: @vsync yes, I'm also waiting to see it! ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, someone proposed exactly that ...

Comment: So basically a SVG, simpler and more random implementation of this? https://jsfiddle.net/ym31k7fe/ - I don't think it's possible with CSS-alone. There's randomness, and other stuff I'm not sure how anyone would implement that in CSS.

Comment: It is possible to do with CSS, but it would take me a few hours and I'm in the middle of a busy workday... just noted that it is possible :) hopefully a person with some skills + freetime is able to come and save-the-day

Comment: Seems that @RokoC.Buljan has already provided a good solution.  I don't think a css only solution is possible because some (unspecified) event must trigger the animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hatches in this solution are a only pseudo-random and repeat every 20 lines. The pattern repeats every 200 px horizontally, but stretches vertically to the height of the wrapping `<svg>` element. Each line is initially vertical, and only after the pattern is fitted it is skewed so the lines appear to be diagonal.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  document.querySelector('#hatches path').classList.add('full');
})
```

```css
#hatches path {
  fill:none;
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:1;
  transition: d 1s linear;
}
#hatches path.full {
  d: path('M 5,0 5,100 M 15,0 15,100 M 25,0 25,100 M 35,0 35,100 M 45,0 45,100 M 55,0 55,100 M 65,0 65,100 M 75,0 75,100 M 85,0 85,100 M 95,0 95,100 M 105,0 105,100 M 115,0 115,100 M 125,0 125,100 M 135,0 135,100 M 145,0 145,100 M 155,0 155,100 M 165,0 165,100 M 175,0 175,100 M 185,0 185,100 M 195,0 195,100')
}
rect { fill: url(#hatches) }
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="300">
  <pattern id="hatches" width="200" height="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" patternTransform="skewX(-45)">
    <path d='M5,37 5,91 M 15,40 15,80 M 25,11 25,59 M 35,26 35,79 M 45,29 45,83 M 55,50 55,98 M 65,20 65,59 M 75,7 75,99 M 85,17 85,56 M 95,33 95,55 M 105,20 105,67 M 115,45 115,55 M 125,18 125,93 M 135,33 135,89 M 145,20 145,98 M 155,14 155,62 M 165,45 165,64 M 175,3 175,53 M 185,20 185,73 M 195,30 195,59' />
  </pattern>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
<button>Fill</button>
```